# Diagonal-type argument for real nets

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, nets

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and suppose we have the following property:

> For every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subseteq X$ such that 
>   $$
> \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq \varepsilon.
> $$

Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq X$ such that 
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 0.
$$
We can show this by using a "diagonal" argument. Let $(x_n^{(k)})_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq X$ have the property that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n^{(k)} \leq k^{-1}.
$$
Now, for all $k$ there exists an $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, whenever $n \geq N_k$, we have $x_n^{(k)} \leq k^{-1}$. Without loss of generality, let's assume that $N_1 < N_2 < \cdots$. Then we define the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows. For $n=1, 2, \dots, N_2$, set $x_n = x_n^{(1)}$. Given that the sequence has been defined up until $N_k$, set $x_n = x_n^{(k)}$ for all $n = N_k + 1, N_k + 2, \dots, N_{k+1}$.

It follows that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N_k$ we have $x_n \leq k^{-1}$, which implies
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 0.
$$

**My question**: Does the same fact hold if we replace sequences with nets? If so, can it be shown via a "diagonal"-type argument?

Comment: It's not at all clear why the sequence you build should be convergent. For instance, consider $X$ the negative numbers and $(x_n^{(k)})$ to be the constant sequence with value $-k$. Then the sequence you build will be $(-1,-2,-3,\dotsc)$ that doesn't converge.

Comment: Good point. I actually just care about the superior limit, though. Let me change the OP.

Comment: Nets are not useful is 1st countable spaces which R is.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I wouldn't say that. Of course all topological properties of a first countable space can be expressed in terms of sequences. Thus, in a sense, we do not need more general nets. But look at the Riemann integral. The collection of lower and upper Darboux sums is indexed by the set of partitions of an interval. In other words, this construction produces nets which are no sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A net $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ in a space $X$ is a function $x : A \to X$ defined on a  directed set $A$. The collection of all nets is very large - it does not even form a *set* (but don't let us go here into the fundaments of set theory).

We shall show the following.

Assume that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a net $(x_\alpha)$ in $X$ such that 
$$
\limsup_{\alpha} x_\alpha \leq \varepsilon.
$$

Then there exists a sequence $(\xi_n)$ in $X$ such that 
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \xi_n \leq 0.
$$

To prove this, we do not need any kind of diagonal argument. In fact, for any $n$ we find a net $(x_\alpha)$ such that $\limsup_{\alpha} x_\alpha \leq 1/n$. In particular, there must exist a $\xi_n = x_{\alpha_n}$ from this net such that $\xi_n \le 2/n$ (otherwise we would have $\limsup_{\alpha} x_\alpha \geq 2/n$). The sequence $(\xi_n)
$ clearly satisfies $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \xi_n \leq 0$ because $\xi_n \le 2/k$
 for $n \ge k$.